# How do I create an image reference in Javascript equivalent to a document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have javascript code that retrieves GPS coordinates from a geotagged image.  I use document.GetElementByID which loads a variable with (as I understand it) the ***reference*** to the HTML image object.  It then passes that reference to my custom code which then retrieves the GPS coordinates from the image.  This all works beautifully.

I want to eliminate the HTML image div and ID, and simply send my function the SAME sort of reference using purely javascript, without using document.GetElementById.

Basically, I want to convert from this:

```
var myimage = document.getElementById("img1");  //img1 

getLocation(myimage, function(location) {
    console.log("latitude is " + location[0] + " and longitude is " + location[1]);
});   //location is the array with the gps coordinates, created by getLocation
```

to something like this:

```
var myimage = "...some image reference here, equivalent to above";

getLocation(myimage, function(location){
console.log("latitude is " + location[0] + " and longitude is " + location[1]);
});   //location is the array with the gps coordinates, created by getLocation
```

I don't want to use HTML divs as eventually I will be retrieving images from a db and using the code to "process" them.  I tried using document.createElement but that didn't seem to work.

If I understand it correctly

```
var x = document.getElementByID("img1");
```

stores a ***reference*** to the image in the variable 'x' whereas

```
var x = document.createElement("img1");
x.setAttribute("src", "img1.jpg");
```

actually creates and stores the image DOM object itself??  In any case, the code using document.createElement didn't successfully process 'x' in the second example, so it appears that isn't the right way to do this.

How would I resolve this?  Thanks.

All:  based on your inputs and various attempts, I've settled on using new Image(); etc. and it works brilliantly.....BUT, only in MOZILLA!  I've set up a sample array of image objects, and the code processes the images in the array in turn, pulling the GPS coordinates and logging them to the console.  In Chrome, however, it only returns a single set for one image, and after lots of trial and error it seems to work ONLY for the image listed in the HTML (which I wanted to remove!)....  Not sure why Mozilla would behave one way and Chrome differently unless it has something to do with cacheing.....in fact, if I refresh in Mozilla it re-loads and re-runs the code perfectly, but in Chrome I don't get the gps coordinates logged when I refresh the browser.  In fact, much of my time was wasted trying to "fix" code that works fine (at least in Mozilla).  Here's the current version:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="exif.js"></script>

</head>
<body>



<br/><br/>
<img src="coussay.jpg" id="img1" />
<br/>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function convertDMtoDD (coordinates, direction) {

//convert the decimal minutes coordinate array to decimal degrees
//set the sign based on direction where "S" or "E" is negative

    gpsdegrees = (coordinates[0]);
    gpsminutes = (coordinates[1]);  
    leftminutes = Math.floor(gpsminutes);   
    rightminutes = (gpsminutes - leftminutes) / 60; 
    leftminutes = leftminutes / 60;  
    rightminutes = leftminutes + rightminutes;
    degdecimal = (gpsdegrees + rightminutes).toFixed(6);

    if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") {

        degdecimal = 0 - degdecimal;

    }

    return degdecimal;

}


function getLocation(myimage, fn) {

    //EXIF.getData in the EXIF.js library gets the EXIF data from the raw image DOM object 

    myimage.onload=EXIF.getData(myimage, function() {


        //EXIF.getTag pulls the various data for each tag such as latitude, longitude, etc.
        //lati and longi are arrays containing decimalminutes values; latd and longd are single values of either "N", "S", "W", or "E")
        var lati = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLatitude");
        var latd = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLatitudeRef");

        var longi = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLongitude");
        var longd = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLongitudeRef");

        var location = [];
        //convert data from decimal minutes to decimal degrees and set direction as neg or pos
        location[0] = convertDMtoDD(lati, latd);
        location[1] = convertDMtoDD(longi, longd);


        fn(location);

    });



}

var imagelist = [

                {name: 'Chateau Coussay', src: 'coussay.jpg'},
                {name: 'Chateau Courlaine', src: 'coulaine.jpg'},
                {name: 'Chateau Sainte-Chapelle', src: 'chapelle.jpg'} 
            ];

for (var i=0; i<imagelist.length; i++)   {  
    var myimage = new Image();

    myimage.src = imagelist[i].src;

    getLocation(myimage, function(location) {

        console.log("latitude is " + location[0] + " longitude is " + location[1]);  

    });

}

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: you can use the [`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) object instead of `document.createElement('img')`: `var x = new Image(); x.src = 'img1.jpg'`. Anyway, it's difficult to answer your question without knowing what information you need from the image within your `getLocation` function

Comment: the getLocation uses the EXIF.js library to extract the EXIF data and specifically pulls EXIF tags for the gps lat, gps long, and the directions then gets the actual GPS coordinates (all working fine).   So, EXIF processes (somehow) the image but the functions use the reference (I think?) to pass the image.  I'm fuzzy as you can tell on the details of how EXIF.js works, but using the document.getElementById to reference the image in the HTML works fine....so my approach was to try to duplicate that reference in Javascript vs pull it from an HTML div.

Comment: exif-js doesn't need your image to be in the document, it just needs to have an src for external files so `var img = new Image; img.src="url"; EXIF.getData(img)` will work. And if you are dealing with user uploaded files, you can even pass directly Blobs so `EXIF.getData(fileInput.files[0])` will work too.

Comment: Rob M. I updated the code per your suggestion...and I'm up and running but only in Mozilla(!).  See the full solution at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the proper tag name **img**, not **img1**.

```
var x = document.createElement("img");
x.setAttribute("src", "img1.jpg");
```

You may also need to add the element into the DOM, perhaps like so:

```
document.getElementById("img-container").appendChild(x);
```

Comment: *You must ...* How do you know it? Do you know the lib OP is using? For most image manipulations or parsing, there is no need to have the image in the document. And since here I guess the lib does only read the EXIF data, I'm pretty sure that at the end only the src is really needed.

Comment: I'm using the exif-js library from GitHub to process/pull out the EXIF tags for the GPS coordinates and direction and then I retrieve the data from the image file....EXIF.js works fine when I pass it the reference in the first example above (generated by document.getElementById).  I assumed "the reference" is more than just the image file 'src'??  I'll try both approaches and see which one(s) work.

Comment: The exif-js documentation indicates you pass it an image as a parameter, "either an image from a <img src="image.jpg"> or a user selected image.

Comment: So I wanted to pass it the image, but not by pulling it from an HTML element or user-selected.  I think that means I need to build the actual DOM in javascript using createElement.